# Modify code of an existing flutter widget

Tags: flutter, github, widget

Flutter has a widget called "Expension tile" which I am willing to modify its code.
unfortunately when I am changing the code of this class an error pops:

```
[Error - 10:28:43 AM] Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
Message: An error occurred while handling textDocument/codeAction request
Code: -32001 
[Error - 10:28:43 AM] An error occurred while handling textDocument/codeAction request: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'packagesAvailableTo' was called on null.
```

So I searched ways to modify it on the internet and the solution was to find the class on GitHub  and fork it, But I couldn't find any flutter widget on GitHub.

how can I solve this issue?

Comment: [tag:git] and [tag:fork] are inappropriate tags here (fork is for Unix/Linux `fork` system calls, not for repository forks). [tag:flutter] seems right though. [tag:github] is probably not, as it's for GitHub-specific issues; as the popup text says, don't use the tag just because some repository is *hosted on* GitHub.